# Inheriting from class with generic type constraint - Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Although this seems as a easy fix, I can't wrap my head around why this does not work.

Here's the files (and also the error we are working with).

Component: `DeliveryTime.razor`

```
@using Not.Important.for.you
@using Foo.Shared;
@inherits ValidationBase
@typeparam T where T : BaseFeatureEntity
                               //~~~~~'BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)': no suitable method found to override"

@namespace Foo.Bar.Code
@if(ArticleEntity is not null)
{
    <div>
        <CardHeader HeaderText="Lieferzeit"/>
        <DataRowInputComponent DataRowIdentifier="Lieferbar in"
                               NonEditable=_isInFullEditMode
                               For="() => ArticleEntity.DeliveryTime"
                               @bind-Value="@ArticleEntity.DeliveryTime" />
    </div>
}
```

Code-behind: `DeliveryTime.razor.cs`

```cs
namespace Foo.Bar.Code
{
    public partial class DeliveryTime<T> : ValidationBase where T : BaseFeatureEntity
    {
        [CascadingParameter(Name = "MainDataEditMode")]
        public MainDataEditMode? MainDataEditMode { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public BaseProductDto<T>? ArticleEntity { get; set; }

        private bool _isInFullEditMode => MainDataEditMode?.EditMode == EditModes.Full;

        public override ResultBase Validate()
        {
            var result = new ResultBase();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Base class: `ValidationBase`

```cs
namespace Foo.Shared
{
    public abstract class ValidationBase
    {
        public abstract ResultBase Validate();
    }
}
```

How does this occur? Did I do something wrong with the inheritance? Am I missing something? Normally I'd figure that this error is just some `;` missing or some other basic/vital line, yet I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does your base class inherit after ComponentBase? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0 I cannot see that it does.

Comment: It does not (inherit from ComponentBase). So as far as Blazor is concerned it's not a component. And it does not have a BuildRenderTree() to override.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Making `ValidationBase` inherit from `ComponentBase` fixed it - thanks

Comment: Ok, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazor component has to inherit after ComponentBase or similar:
[ComponentBase class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
[How to write Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

You could make `ValidationBase` inherit after `ComponentBase`

```
namespace Foo.Shared
{
    public abstract class ValidationBase : ComponentBase
    {
        public abstract ResultBase Validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This error message occurs when you are trying to inherit from a class that doesn't have a suitable BuildRenderTree method to override.
In Blazor, you need to inherit from the ComponentBase class to create a component or a related component class.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if ValidationBase inherited after ComponentBase?